# Images on the left side and its description on the right side when clicking the image on the same page

Tags: jquery

I need to implement a thing in my website
ie: If I click on any image which are present in the left side of the page , its description should appear on the right hand side of same page without reloading. Ie : in other div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a div element with each image and set its visibility to hidden. then attach an onclick listener to each image something along the line of this:

```
    <div>
        <img>
        <div>description</div>
    </div>

    $( document).ready( function() {
        $( ".myImages" ).click( function() {
            $( this ).next().css( 'visibility', 'visible' );
        });
    });
```

Comment: actually display would probably be better than visibility